# How to share or copy files beetween shared folders in linux via PHP

Tags: php, file

I have a very hard mission to accomplish.
We have a dedicated server outside  our company and we also have two servers inside our company.
We need to copy files from server 1 to server 2 programatically via PHP, but the files are inside the /home/server1/files and  should go to /home/server2/files.

When the users select 10 files to group accordingly to some criteria, these files must be sent to another server.

We were using copy when we had only one server, and everything was okay...
but now, the system is down, because we have two servers....

When using one server I could use this:

```
copy('/home/server/files/file.txt', '/home/server/files/group-1/file.txt');
```

now it has to be:

```
copy('/home/server1/files/file.txt', '/home/server2/files/group-1/file.txt');
```

But I don't know how to sent files via servers.

Comment: your mission is not very hard ... check out curl http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php

Comment: Can I access linux home folder with Curl and PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are quite a few different ways to copy files between servers. I can think of the following:

1. **Send over SSH**. You could use [php's SCP library](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ssh2-scp-send.php)
2. **Send via SFTP**. Requires a FTP server be setup on server2 and code to be changed to use [ftp](http://php.net/ftp).
3. **Copy via [NFS](http://nfs.sourceforge.net/)**. Requires NFS to be setup. Once it is you could mount your server2 to /home/server2 and hopefully not need to make any programming changes.
4. **Send via a webservice call (REST or SOAP)**. Requires code to be setup on server2 to listen for file sending.

Comment: I will ask the server administrator to install the scp library. It seems to be the best solution